# Where does Dojo store required modules? Need to investigate if something is loaded

Tags: module, dojo, require

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could get a reference to the actual array or associative array or whatever data structure stores the loaded modules in Dojo.

What I am doing is this: I work in a team. We have a fairly complex page that takes forever to load because it has to wait for some Ajax calls that take a long time. Also, it relies on a lot of required Dojo modules. So my coworker devised a way to load this "template" once, and then refresh the "actual" page I am working on by use of a hashtag listener.

So anyways, in order to speed up development, I need to be able to reload custom Dojo modules I've edited. I mean, when I edit one of our modules, I don't want to have to reload everything else. Just that one module.

I was using require.undef, but that just stopped working. And I'd like to see if I can get a reference to the place where the modules are actually stored, so I can check it out in Firebug.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you break up the app so you can test parts in isolation? That sounds like a more scalable/testable approach for development.

Comment: I guess. But I know there has to be a data store somewhere. Also I'm a really hyper developer. ADHD. I don't really have the patience for that, loal. Lol + coal = loal. No reason for coal.

---

But anyways, I am quite certain that there MUST be an actual object with this data SOMEWHERE in Dojo. And from what I understand, in JS you have access to pretty much everything. So, I know it exists, I am just not sure how to get to it.